# PHP ["XSS" injection] using str_replace vs null character (\0), i.e java\0script:alert(\"XSS\")

Tags: php, xss, str-replace, double-quotes, single-quotes

About 2 of some of the Websites we did got hacked. We spent hours trying to see what went wrong. The loophole was the `str_replace` vs `\0` the *[Null Char]* .

While using `str_replace` with `Single Quotes [']`.

**Something like:**

```
    $str = 'java\0scr\0ip\0t:alert(\"XSS\")';
    $clean_null_chars = str_replace('\\0','_[_blabla_]_',$str);

//Show the cleaned version
    var_dump($clean_null_chars); // string 'java_[_blabla_]_scr_[_blabla_]_ip_[_blabla_]_t:alert(\"XSS\")' (length=62);

        echo $clean_null_chars; //java_[_blabla_]_scr_[_blabla_]_ip_[_blabla_]_t:alert(\"XSS\")
```

However, using `str_replace` with `Double Quotes ["]`, Nothing happens

**Something like:**

```
 $str= "java\0scr\0ip\0t:alert(\"XSS\")";
        $clean_null_chars = str_replace('\\0','_[_blabla_]_',$str);

    //Show the cleaned version
        var_dump($clean_null_chars); //string 'java�scr�ip�t:alert("XSS")' (length=26); 
    // ....[Notice the _Null Char_  rendered as question marks in var_dump]

   echo $clean_null_chars;// javascript:alert("XSS")
```

Thus some genius managed to abuse the loophole.

Is this a normal behavior for `str_replace` when either `Single Quotes` or `Double Quotes` are involved?

here http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php they use both `[']` and `["]` no mention of different behaviors.

Any Ideas??

Comment: Octal escapes only work in double quoted strings. And it should be `"\0"` not `"\\0"` anyway.

Comment: @mario I think the whole-world should know what you said... this will save many from heart-attacks!

Comment: Do you have any documentation or reference (link) for that?... I think it will help alot!

Comment: It's [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). More importantly here I think you shouldn't try to build your own XSS protection. There's heaps more edge cases. Just use entity encoding for any input and be done. Or use HTMLPurifier or else for completely safe data reuse.

Comment: Sure....You can post an answer with the reference and the URL for it to be _Accepted_